# Android studio Giraffe Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources: error

Tags: android, android-studio

Everytime I run Android studio giraffe I always get this error message:

[image]

How can I find and fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the android plugin was not found. You have to make sure that in your `settings.gradle.kts` the repositories are defined. Something like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
  }
  dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

See the [gradle settings documentation](https://developer.android.com/build#settings-file) for more information.

Comment: how do I access the settings.gradle.kts file? Sorry I'm a beginner at this

Comment: It's in the root folder of your project.

Comment: I looked at it using Android Studion and the only visible file I can see is the build.gradle.kts, but when I open the file using file explorer I can see it.

Comment: You have to change the android view to project view on the top left corner(over your files/folders in Android studio), in order to see all files. However you can just open the settings file with any editor.